# I have a log file where I need to get the output as specified and I need the logic to write in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

Below is the log file and the expected output. The file output should have the CustomerName and Size they have downloaded. There is a CustomerName:John has downloaded twice so in the final output I need to get the total size he has downloaded. I need help with writing a shell script.

Thank you

```
01-01-2012 01:13:36 Blah blah : blah CustomerName:Sam downloaded Blah Size:5432 bytes Carrier:Company-A 
01-01-2012 01:13:45 Blah blah : blah CustomerName:John downloaded Blah Size:38655 bytes Carrier:Company-S 
01-01-2012 01:13:47 Blah blah : blah CustomerName:Dave downloaded Blah Size:25632 bytes Carrier:Company-A 
01-01-2012 01:13:50 Blah blah : blah CustomerName:John downloaded Blah Size:7213 bytes Carrier:Company-S 
01-01-2012 01:13:58 Blah blah : blah CustomerName:Kristy downloaded Blah Size:70100 bytes Carrier:Company-V
```

Expected output

```
CustomerName: Sam Size: 5432
CustomerName: John Size: 45868
CustomerName: Dave Size: 25632
CustomerName: Kristy Size: 70100
```

Comment: This isn't a service to do your work. You need to post what you've tried first.

Comment: I have used akw to separate out the columns CustomerName and Size then I have redirected the output to a new script file. I am stuck with getting the logic of adding the names and size into arrays by removing the duplicate eg: CustomerName: John in the log file.

Comment: You need to post some code.

Comment: awk '{print $7,$10}' question1.txt > idea.sh I have saved the log in the .txt and separatehed the columns and redirected them to idea.sh. I am new to  programming/scripting and I just started learning shell scripting.

Comment: Edit that into your question.  Comments don't always stick around.

Comment: @shivaji, did any of these solutions help you?

Answer (score 2):

Try this-

```
awk -F '[ :]' '{name[$11]++ ; size[$11]+=$15} END \
{for (i in name) print "CustomerName: ", i, "Size:" size[i]}' test
```

Where `test` is the name of the input file.

Output-

```
CustomerName:  Dave Size:25632
CustomerName:  John Size:45868
CustomerName:  Sam Size:5432
CustomerName:  Kristy Size:70100
```

Explanation-

`-F '[ :]'` sets the delimiter to be a `space` and the `:`. Hence the columns get numbered differently.

I define two arrays. The array `name` contains the names of the different people.
The array `size` has the keys based on people's names but contains the sizes of the downloads.

In the part after the `END`, I'm iterating over the names in the `name` array and simply getting the values of the names and the sizes. I've also added some text into the `print` part as per your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cat xxx.txt | awk -F ":" '{print $5" "$6}' | awk '{print $1" "$5}' | awk '{arr[$1]+=$2} END {for (i in arr) {print i,arr[i]}}'

Dave 25632
John 45868
Sam 5432
Kristy 70100
```

where `xxx.txt` is the input file

---

Explanation about `awk '{arr[$1]+=$2} END {for (i in arr) {print i,arr[i]}}'`:

`{arr[$1]+=$2}` will create a `map` which taking the name as  key and number as value,  and if the specific key exists, add the number to the value, and `END` block will be executed after all lines are processed by `awk` , which is print the `map` in this case. [Read more about the END block](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-BEGIN_002fEND.html)

Comment: can you please explain of what you did after the second pipe

Comment: This isn't in the output format requested by OP. Also you're calling `awk` three times. Not necessary. Check out my solution.

Comment: And you don't need to do `cat xyz | awk `. `awk` is capable of reading its own input. Check out this- http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html

Answer (score 0):

```
cat InputFile |awk -F'blah' '{print $3}'|awk -F'downloaded Blah' '{print $1 $2}'|awk -F'bytes' '{print $1}'|awk '{print $1" "$2}'|sed 's/:/\ :\ /g'
```

or

```
`#!/bin/bash
cat $1 |\   # $1 is input file name from command line.
awk -F'blah' '{print $3}'|\ 
awk -F'downloaded Blah' '{print $1 $2}'|\  # 
awk -F'bytes' '{print $1}'|\
awk '{print $1" "$2}'|\
sed 's/:/\ :\ /g'`
```

Both are same thing, just above one written in single line format and second one you can keep it as script which you can modify later and understand better.

in awk, `-F` is delimiter to cut the string, which makes it more easy to understand and get output easily. As you have mentioned you want spaces before and after `:`, I have used sed for it. Both will give output like:

```
CustomerName : Sam Size : 5432
CustomerName : John Size : 38655
CustomerName : Dave Size : 25632
CustomerName : John Size : 7213
CustomerName : Kristy Size : 70100
```

Comment: You don't need `cat | awk | awk | awk | awk | sed`! Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `gsub`to weed out non-digits from `$10`:

```
$ awk '
{
    gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",$10)      # remove non-digits
    a[$7]+=$10                 # count the sizes grouping on the name
}
END {                          # in the end
    for(i in a)
        print i, "Size:" a[i]  # output
}' file
CustomerName:John Size:45868
CustomerName:Sam Size:5432
CustomerName:Kristy Size:70100
CustomerName:Dave Size:25632
```